# com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: null value in entry: crashlytics=null

Tags: android

com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: null value in entry: crashlytics=null   getting this error while syn up the gradle android studio

```
deleted .gradle folder but not working . unable to build the project
```